# FliCard and ListView A strange visibility bug in Android

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview, visibility

I am trying to implement a FlipCard behavior in a ListView for my items and the bug is that my convertView don't update its visibility state according to the visibility I set in the getView method. It's like nobody cares of of my visibility changes.
To reproduce the problem: click on an item picture (sun, cloud...), it will flip the item and present its backside. Then scroll up or down until the convertView flipped is reused by a View that is not flipped. The not flipped view will not display its content anymore.
The first item should displays its content but it displays nothing because the convertView used (the one gave by the getView parameter) had its visibility set to GONE the last time it was used.
[image]

You can find the full project here:
https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/ForecastYahooRest and you have to check out the branch "flipcard"

So the ArrayAdapter involves:

```
package com.android2ee.formation.restservice.sax.forecastyahoo.view.forecast.arrayadpater;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android2ee.formation.restservice.sax.forecastyahoo.R;
import com.android2ee.formation.restservice.sax.forecastyahoo.transverse.model.YahooForcast;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Mathias Seguy (Android2EE)
 * @goals
 *        This class aims to display the forecast in the listView
 */
public class ForecastArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YahooForcast> {

    /**
     * Handler to launch the animation runnable
     */
    Handler handlerForAnimation;
    /**
     * To know when the item is flipped or not
     * When flipped it show us its back side else its front side
     */
    SparseBooleanArray isFlipped;

    /**
     * To detect the first launch
     */
    int notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber = 0;
    /**
     * The layout inflater
     */
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    /**
     * The Context
     */
    Context ctx;
    /**
     * To know if the device is postJellyBean or not
     */
    boolean postJB;
    /**
     * To know if the device is postHoneyComb or not
     */
    boolean postHC;
    /**
     * Drawable used for the backside of the item
     */
    Drawable[] drawableBackground;


    /**
     *
     * @param context
     * @param forecast
     */
    public ForecastArrayAdapter(Context context, List<YahooForcast> forecast) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_forecast, forecast);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ctx = context;
        postJB = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.postJB);
        postHC = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.postHC);
        //instantiate the handler
        handlerForAnimation = new Handler();
        isFlipped=new SparseBooleanArray();
        drawableBackground=new Drawable[5];
        drawableBackground[0]=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back1);
        drawableBackground[1]=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back2);
        drawableBackground[2]=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back3);
        drawableBackground[3]=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back4);
        drawableBackground[4]=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back5);
    }

    /**
     * Private static better than temp
     */
    private static View rowView;

    /**
     * Private static better than temp
     */
    private static YahooForcast forcast;
    /**
     * Private static better than temp
     */
    private static ViewHolder viewHolder;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","getView "+position);
        rowView = convertView;
        forcast = getItem(position);
        if (rowView == null) {
            // always add the layout, the parent and false
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_forecast, null, false);
            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(rowView,position);
            rowView.setTag(vh);
        }
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        //used for animation
        viewHolder.currentPosition=position;
        if (postJB) {
            viewHolder.getImvIcon().setBackground(forcast.getImage());
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setBackground(drawableBackground[position%5]);
        } else {
            viewHolder.getImvIcon().setBackgroundDrawable(forcast.getImage());
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setBackgroundDrawable(drawableBackground[position % 5]);
        }
        if (forcast.getDate() != null) {
            viewHolder.getTxvDate().setText(DateFormat.format("E dd MMM", forcast.getDate()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getTxvDate().setText("unknown");
        }

        viewHolder.getTxvTendance().setText(forcast.getTendance());
        if (forcast.getTempMax() != -1000) {
            viewHolder.getTxvMax().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getTxvMin().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getTxvMax().setText(ctx.getString(R.string.max, forcast.getTempMax()));
            viewHolder.getTxvMin().setText(ctx.getString(R.string.min, forcast.getTempMin()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getTxvMax().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.getTxvMin().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (forcast.getTemp() != -1000) {
            viewHolder.getTxvCurrent().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getTxvCurrent().setText(ctx.getString(R.string.temp, forcast.getTemp()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getTxvCurrent().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // launch animations to show the update to the user (not the first time but only when refreshing)
        //because the first time is not an update, it's just loading data from db
        if (notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber >=2) {
            viewHolder.launchUpdateAnimation(notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber);
        }
        //and finally manage the visibility of the side : front or back side is visible
        manageSideVisibility(position);
        return rowView;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()
     */
    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber++;
    }
    /**************************************************
     * Flipping Animation tricks
     * **************************************************
     */

    /**
     * If the element has been flipped, flip it else set it has not flipped
     * @param position
     */
    private void manageSideVisibility(int position){
        if(isFlipped.get(position)){
            //the backside is visible
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            //the ffront is visible
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    /******************************************************************************************/
    /** Runnable for animation **************************************************************************/
    /******************************************************************************************/
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        /**
         * The viewHolder that contains the view to animate
         */
        private ViewHolder vh;

        public MyRunnable(ViewHolder vh) {
            this.vh=vh;
        }

        public void run() {
            vh.animateUpdate();
        }
    }

    /******************************************************************************************/
    /** The ViewHolder pattern **************************************************************************/
    /******************************************************************************************/

    private class ViewHolder {
        View view;
        LinearLayout linRoot;
        TextView txvDate;
        TextView txvTendance;
        ImageView imvIcon;
        TextView txvCurrent;
        TextView txvMin;
        TextView txvMax;
        TextView txvUpdating;
        //For Update animation
        Animation updateAnimation;
        MyRunnable animationRunnable;
        int dataTimeStamp=0;
        //For animatibbbbbbon
        ImageView imvBack;
        int currentPosition;
        //PostHoneyComb
        Animator flipAnimatorIn;
        Animator flipAnimatorOut;
        Animator reverseFlipAnimatorIn;
        Animator reverseFlipAnimatorOut;
        AnimatorSet setFlip;
        AnimatorSet setReverse;
        //PreHoneyComb
        Animation animInLegacy;
        Animation animOutLegacy;
        int id;
        /**
         * @param rowview
         */
        private ViewHolder(View rowview,int position) {
            super();
            this.view = rowview;
            animationRunnable=new MyRunnable(this);
            id=position;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvDate
         */
        public final TextView getTxvDate() {
            if (null == txvDate) {
                txvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            }
            return txvDate;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvTendance
         */
        public final TextView getTxvTendance() {
            if (null == txvTendance) {
                txvTendance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_tendance);
            }
            return txvTendance;
        }
        /**
         * @return the imvIcon
         */
        public final ImageView getImvIcon() {
            if (null == imvIcon) {
                imvIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                imvIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(postHC){
                            animateItem();
                        }else{
                            flipItemLegacy();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return imvIcon;
        }
        /**
         * @return the imvBack
         */
        public final ImageView getImvBack() {
            if (null == imvBack) {
                imvBack = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imvBack);
                imvBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(postHC){
                            reverseAnimateItem();
                        }else{
                            reverseItemLegacy();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return imvBack;
        }
        /**
         * @return the txvTendance
         */
        public final TextView getTxvUpdating() {
            if (null == txvUpdating) {
                txvUpdating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_updating);
            }
            return txvUpdating;
        }
        /**
         * @return the txvCurrent
         */
        public final TextView getTxvCurrent() {
            if (null == txvCurrent) {
                txvCurrent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_current);
                txvCurrent.setText("Toto");
            }
            return txvCurrent;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvMin
         */
        public final TextView getTxvMin() {
            if (null == txvMin) {
                txvMin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_min);
            }
            return txvMin;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvMax
         */
        public final TextView getTxvMax() {
            if (null == txvMax) {
                txvMax = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_max);
            }
            return txvMax;
        }

        /**
         * @return the linRoot
         */
        public final LinearLayout getLinRoot() {
            if (null == linRoot) {
                linRoot = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lay_item);
            }
            return linRoot;
        }
        /**************************************************
         * Animation tricks
         * All Version
         * The UpdateAnimation
         * **************************************************
         */
        /**
         * Launch the Update Animation
         */
        public void animateUpdate() {
            if (updateAnimation==null) {
                updateAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_item_updated);
                updateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        getTxvUpdating().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            getTxvUpdating().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                });
            }

            if (isFlipped.get(currentPosition)) {
                getImvBack().startAnimation(updateAnimation);
            } else {
                //run it
                getLinRoot().startAnimation(updateAnimation);
            }
        }
        /**
         * Launch the Update Animation
         */
        public void launchUpdateAnimation(int ndscCallsNumber){
            if(dataTimeStamp!=ndscCallsNumber) {
                //it means an already runnable is associated with this item
                //we need to remove it (else it gonna run the animation twice
                //and it's strange for the user)
                handlerForAnimation.removeCallbacks(animationRunnable);
                //then launched it in few seconds
                handlerForAnimation.postDelayed(animationRunnable, 300 * currentPosition);
                Log.e("tag", "launchUpdateAnimation in " + 300 * currentPosition + " for item " + currentPosition);
                dataTimeStamp=ndscCallsNumber;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************
         * Animation tricks
         * preHoneyComb : 4 Gingerbread in fact
         * **************************************************
         */
        private void flipItemLegacy(){
            if(animInLegacy==null){
                animInLegacy= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.forecast_item_in);
            }
            if(animOutLegacy==null){
                animOutLegacy= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.forecast_item_out);
            }
            animOutLegacy.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","flipItemLegacy onAnimationEnd called ");
                    getImvBack().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getImvBack().startAnimation(animInLegacy);
                    getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            });
            getLinRoot().startAnimation(animOutLegacy);

            isFlipped.put(currentPosition,true);

        }
        private void reverseItemLegacy(){
            if(animInLegacy==null){
                animInLegacy= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.forecast_item_in);
            }
            if(animOutLegacy==null){
                animOutLegacy= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.forecast_item_out);
            }
            animInLegacy.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    getLinRoot().startAnimation(animInLegacy);
                    getImvBack().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            });
            getImvBack().startAnimation(animOutLegacy);

            isFlipped.put(currentPosition,false);

        }

        /**************************************************
         * Animation tricks
         * postHoneyComb
         * **************************************************
         */

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void animateItem(){
            initialiseFlipAnimator();
            setFlip.start();
            isFlipped.put(currentPosition,true);
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void reverseAnimateItem(){
            initialiseReverseFlipAnimator();
            setReverse.start();
            isFlipped.put(currentPosition,false);
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void initialiseReverseFlipAnimator() {
            if(reverseFlipAnimatorIn==null){
                reverseFlipAnimatorIn= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.flip_in);
                reverseFlipAnimatorIn.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        getImvBack().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                reverseFlipAnimatorIn.setTarget(getLinRoot());
                reverseFlipAnimatorOut= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(),R.animator.flip_out);
                reverseFlipAnimatorOut.setTarget(imvBack);
                setReverse=new AnimatorSet();
                setReverse.playTogether(reverseFlipAnimatorIn,reverseFlipAnimatorOut);
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void initialiseFlipAnimator(){
            Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","initialiseFlipAnimator");
            if(flipAnimatorIn==null){
                flipAnimatorIn= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(),R.animator.flip_in);
                flipAnimatorIn.setTarget(getImvBack());
                flipAnimatorOut= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(),R.animator.flip_out);
                flipAnimatorOut.setTarget(getLinRoot());
                flipAnimatorIn.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        Log.e("tag","anim onAnimationStart");
                        getImvBack().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        Log.e("tag","anim onAnimationEnd");
                        getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                setFlip=new AnimatorSet();
                setFlip.playTogether(flipAnimatorIn, flipAnimatorOut);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public abstract class SimpleAnimatorListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
        /**
         * <p>Notifies the start of the animation.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The started animation.
         */
        public abstract void onAnimationStart(Animator animation);

        /**
         * <p>Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked
         * for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The animation which reached its end.
         */
        public abstract void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) ;

        /**
         * <p>Notifies the cancellation of the animation. This callback is not invoked
         * for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The animation which was canceled.
         */
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            onAnimationEnd(animation);
        }

        /**
         * <p>Notifies the repetition of the animation.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The animation which was repeated.
         */
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            onAnimationStart(animation);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, I dive into that bug and I still don't understand (I had a lot of logs) so 
my problem is here, the view tells me, it's Visible,

[image]
but it's not displayed
[image]

A simple way to reproduce the problem, go in landscape mode, flip the first two items, scroll to the end of the list.

Thanks a billion to those who will try to answer.
Mathias

Answer (score 0):

Youpi, I found !!
**Summary**
Ok, for me, it's a bug or an over optimised behavior.
So when my view is flipped I hide the front to show the back, and unflipped, I hide the back to show the front.
The problem is if I hide the front in the view v1 associated with the item n1. I scroll. Then this view is reused as a convertView in the getView method with the items n2. But for the item n2, we display the front...
And the bug occurs: The front view has been almost deleted/garbage collected or what ever but is not here anymore. It answers to functions' calls but its inner state is wrong. So It tells you, I am visible but it's not, it's a ghost.

**My comprehension:**
What I think (it's an hypothesis)
So the point here is an over optimisation of the ListView:
When a view went in the pool of convert views, the system destroys the ressources that are in the "Visibility Gone" state. I mean the Views of the ViewGroup root that have Visibility=Gone.

**My comprehension is Wrong**
So Romain Guy told me, "ListView does not destroy GONE views. Esp. since it doesn't look at children of recycled views. And if you can call a method on a View it has clearly not been GC'd. It could be a bug in the UI Toolkit drawing or in the adapter."
.... Ok, I will continue do dive in my problem to understand so.

**The solution**:
So the solution is obvious, I need two convert views pools, one with front visible by default, the other with back visible by default. So I create two layouts, one with the front visible, the other with the back visible, i use the getViewTypeCount() and the getItemViewType(int position) methods, and 3 minutes latter it was working.

**The conclusion**
As conclusion, when, in ListView, you hide and show elements in your items, you need to define as much as configurations as convertViews pools.
 :( I am sad to understand that and if the bug was not there to prove it, I will never believe that.

**The project**
You can find the full project here:
https://github.com/MathiasSeguy-Android2EE/ForecastYahooRest and you have to check out the branch "flipcard" is updated.

**The Code:**

```
package com.android2ee.formation.restservice.sax.forecastyahoo.view.forecast.arrayadpater;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android2ee.formation.restservice.sax.forecastyahoo.R;
import com.android2ee.formation.restservice.sax.forecastyahoo.transverse.model.YahooForcast;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * @author Mathias Seguy (Android2EE)
 * @goals This class aims to display the forecast in the listView
 */
public class ForecastArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<YahooForcast> {

    /**
     * Handler to launch the animation runnable
     */
    Handler handlerForAnimation;
    /**
     * To know when the item is flipped or not
     * When flipped it show us its back side else its front side
     */
    SparseBooleanArray isFlipped;

    /**
     * To detect the first launch
     */
    int notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber = 0;
    /**
     * The layout inflater
     */
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    /**
     * The Context
     */
    Context ctx;
    /**
     * To know if the device is postJellyBean or not
     */
    boolean postJB;
    /**
     * To know if the device is postHoneyComb or not
     */
    boolean postHC;
    /**
     * Drawable used for the backside of the item
     */
    Drawable[] drawableBackground;
    int[] drawableRes;


    /**
     * @param context
     * @param forecast
     */
    public ForecastArrayAdapter(Context context, List<YahooForcast> forecast) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_forecast, forecast);
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ctx = context;
        postJB = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.postJB);
        postHC = context.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.postHC);
        //instantiate the handler
        handlerForAnimation = new Handler();
        isFlipped = new SparseBooleanArray(5);
        drawableRes = new int[5];
        drawableRes[0] = R.drawable.back1;
        drawableRes[1] = R.drawable.back2;
        drawableRes[2] = R.drawable.back3;
        drawableRes[3] = R.drawable.back4;
        drawableRes[4] = R.drawable.back5;
        drawableBackground = new Drawable[5];
        drawableBackground[0] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back1);
        drawableBackground[1] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back2);
        drawableBackground[2] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back3);
        drawableBackground[3] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back4);
        drawableBackground[4] = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back5);
    }

    /**
     * Private static better than temp
     */
    private static View rowView;

    /**
     * Private static better than temp
     */
    private static YahooForcast forcast;
    /**
     * Private static better than temp
     */
    private static ViewHolder viewHolder;

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#getView(int, android.view.View, android.view.ViewGroup)
     */
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        rowView = convertView;
        forcast = getItem(position);
        if (rowView == null) {
            if(getItemViewType(position)==0){
                //then used the layout of flipped view
                // always add the layout, the parent and false
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_forecast, null, false);
            }else{
                //then used the layout for not flipped view
                // always add the layout, the parent and false
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_forecast, null, false);
            }

            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(rowView, position);
            rowView.setTag(vh);
        }
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        //used for animation
        viewHolder.setCurrentPosition(position);
        if (postJB) {
            viewHolder.getImvIcon().setBackground(forcast.getImage());
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setBackground(drawableBackground[position % 5]);
        } else {
            viewHolder.getImvIcon().setBackgroundDrawable(forcast.getImage());
            //if you don't use setBackgroundResource nothing happens on Gingerbread (deep sadness sometimes)
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setBackgroundResource(drawableRes[position % 5]);
        }
        if (forcast.getDate() != null) {
            viewHolder.getTxvDate().setText(DateFormat.format("E dd MMM", forcast.getDate()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getTxvDate().setText("unknown");
        }

        viewHolder.getTxvTendance().setText(forcast.getTendance());
        if (forcast.getTempMax() != -1000) {
            viewHolder.getTxvMax().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getTxvMin().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getTxvMax().setText(ctx.getString(R.string.max, forcast.getTempMax()));
            viewHolder.getTxvMin().setText(ctx.getString(R.string.min, forcast.getTempMin()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getTxvMax().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.getTxvMin().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        if (forcast.getTemp() != -1000) {
            viewHolder.getTxvCurrent().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getTxvCurrent().setText(ctx.getString(R.string.temp, forcast.getTemp()));
        } else {
            viewHolder.getTxvCurrent().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        // launch animations to show the update to the user (not the first time but only when refreshing)
        //because the first time is not an update, it's just loading data from db
        if (notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber >= 2) {
            viewHolder.launchUpdateAnimation(notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber);
        }
        //and finally manage the visibility of the side : front or back side is visible
        return rowView;
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged()
     */
    @Override
    public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
        super.notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyDataSetChangedCallsNumber++;
    }
    /***********************************************************
     *  Trying to fix the bug of the visible view not displayed
     *  by managing 2 pools of views
     **********************************************************/
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        //Two pools: the one for flipped views, the other not flipped views
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //If the View is flipped then pick in the pool 0
        //else pick in the pool 1
        return isFlipped.get(position)?0:1;
    }

    /**************************************************
     * Flipping Animation tricks
     * **************************************************
     */

    /**
     * If the element has been flipped, flip it else set it has not flipped
     *
     * @param position
     */
    private void manageSideVisibility(int position) {
        if (isFlipped.get(position)) {
            Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","ImvBack Visible"+position);
            //the backside is visible
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.getImvBack().invalidate();
        } else {
            Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","ImvBack GONE"+position);
            //the ffront is visible
            viewHolder.getImvBack().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            viewHolder.getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.getLinRoot().invalidate();
        }
        printView("ImvBack",viewHolder.getImvBack(),position);
        printView("LinRoot",viewHolder.getLinRoot(),position);
    }
    public void printView(String viewName,View view,int position){
        Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","("+viewName+","+position+") getWidth()="+view.getWidth());
        Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter","("+viewName+","+position+") getHeight()="+view.getHeight());
        Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter", "(" + viewName + "," + position + ") getHeight()=" + view.getBackground());
        Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter", "(" + viewName + "," + position + ") getVisibility()=" + getVisibility(view));
    }

    public String getVisibility(View view){
        switch (view.getVisibility()){
            case View.GONE:
                return "GONE";
            case View.VISIBLE:
                return "VISIBLE";
            case View.INVISIBLE:
                return "INVISIBLE";
        }
        return "Unknow";
    }
    /******************************************************************************************/
    /** Runnable for animation **************************************************************************/
    /**
     * **************************************************************************************
     */
    public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
        /**
         * The viewHolder that contains the view to animate
         */
        private ViewHolder vh;

        public MyRunnable(ViewHolder vh) {
            this.vh = vh;
        }

        public void run() {
            vh.animateUpdate();
        }
    }

    public void printisFlipp(String methodName) {
        for (int i = 0;i < 5; i++){
            Log.e("ForecastArrayAdapter", "in("+methodName+") isFlipped[" + i + "]=" + isFlipped.get(i));
        }
    }
    /******************************************************************************************/
    /** The ViewHolder pattern **************************************************************************/
    /******************************************************************************************/

    private class ViewHolder {
        View view;
        LinearLayout linRoot;
        TextView txvDate;
        TextView txvTendance;
        ImageView imvIcon;
        TextView txvCurrent;
        TextView txvMin;
        TextView txvMax;
        TextView txvUpdating;
        //For Update animation
        Animation updateAnimation;
        MyRunnable animationRunnable;
        int dataTimeStamp=0;
        //For animation
        ImageView imvBack;
        int currentPosition;

        public int getCurrentPosition() {
            return currentPosition;
        }

        public void setCurrentPosition(int currentPosition) {
            this.currentPosition = currentPosition;
        }

        //PostHoneyComb
        Animator flipAnimatorIn;
        Animator flipAnimatorOut;
        Animator reverseFlipAnimatorIn;
        Animator reverseFlipAnimatorOut;
        AnimatorSet setFlip;
        AnimatorSet setReverse;
        //PreHoneyComb
        Animation animInLegacy;
        Animation animOutLegacy;
        int id;
        /**
         * @param rowview
         */
        private ViewHolder(View rowview,int position) {
            super();
            this.view = rowview;
            animationRunnable=new MyRunnable(this);
            id=position;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvDate
         */
        public final TextView getTxvDate() {
            if (null == txvDate) {
                txvDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            }
            return txvDate;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvTendance
         */
        public final TextView getTxvTendance() {
            if (null == txvTendance) {
                txvTendance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_tendance);
            }
            return txvTendance;
        }
        /**
         * @return the imvIcon
         */
        public final ImageView getImvIcon() {
            if (null == imvIcon) {
                imvIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
                imvIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(postHC){
                            animateItem();
                        }else{
                            flipItemLegacy();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return imvIcon;
        }
        /**
         * @return the imvBack
         */
        public final ImageView getImvBack() {
            if (null == imvBack) {
                imvBack = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imvBack);
                imvBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(postHC){
                            reverseAnimateItem();
                        }else{
                            reverseItemLegacy();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            return imvBack;
        }
        /**
         * @return the txvTendance
         */
        public final TextView getTxvUpdating() {
            if (null == txvUpdating) {
                txvUpdating = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_updating);
            }
            return txvUpdating;
        }
        /**
         * @return the txvCurrent
         */
        public final TextView getTxvCurrent() {
            if (null == txvCurrent) {
                txvCurrent = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_current);
                txvCurrent.setText("Toto");
            }
            return txvCurrent;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvMin
         */
        public final TextView getTxvMin() {
            if (null == txvMin) {
                txvMin = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_min);
            }
            return txvMin;
        }

        /**
         * @return the txvMax
         */
        public final TextView getTxvMax() {
            if (null == txvMax) {
                txvMax = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txv_max);
            }
            return txvMax;
        }

        /**
         * @return the linRoot
         */
        public final LinearLayout getLinRoot() {
            if (null == linRoot) {
                linRoot = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.lay_item);
            }
            return linRoot;
        }
        /**************************************************
         * Animation tricks
         * All Version
         * The UpdateAnimation
         * **************************************************
         */
        /**
         * Launch the Update Animation
         */
        public void animateUpdate() {
            if (updateAnimation==null) {
                updateAnimation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_item_updated);
                updateAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        getTxvUpdating().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            getTxvUpdating().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                });
            }

            if (isFlipped.get(currentPosition)) {
                getImvBack().startAnimation(updateAnimation);
            } else {
                //run it
                getLinRoot().startAnimation(updateAnimation);
            }
        }
        /**
         * Launch the Update Animation
         */
        public void launchUpdateAnimation(int ndscCallsNumber){
            if(dataTimeStamp!=ndscCallsNumber) {
                //it means an already runnable is associated with this item
                //we need to remove it (else it gonna run the animation twice
                //and it's strange for the user)
                handlerForAnimation.removeCallbacks(animationRunnable);
                //then launched it in few seconds
                handlerForAnimation.postDelayed(animationRunnable, 300 * currentPosition);
                dataTimeStamp=ndscCallsNumber;
            }
        }

        /**************************************************
         * Animation tricks
         * preHoneyComb : 4 Gingerbread in fact
         * **************************************************
         */
        private void flipItemLegacy(){
            initLegacyAnimation();
            getLinRoot().startAnimation(animOutLegacy);
            isFlipped.put(getCurrentPosition(), true);
        }


        private void reverseItemLegacy(){
            initLegacyAnimation();
            getImvBack().startAnimation(animInLegacy);
            isFlipped.put(getCurrentPosition(),false);
        }
        private void initLegacyAnimation() {
            if(animInLegacy==null){
                animInLegacy= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.forecast_item_in);
                animInLegacy.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getImvBack().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                });
            }
            if(animOutLegacy==null){
                animOutLegacy= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(),R.anim.forecast_item_out);
                animOutLegacy.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        getImvBack().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        /**************************************************
         * Animation tricks
         * postHoneyComb
         * **************************************************
         */

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void animateItem(){
            initialiseFlipAnimator();
            setFlip.start();
            isFlipped.put(getCurrentPosition(), true);
            printisFlipp("animateItem");
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void reverseAnimateItem(){
            initialiseReverseFlipAnimator();
            setReverse.start();
            isFlipped.put(getCurrentPosition(), false);
            printisFlipp("animateItem");
        }
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void initialiseReverseFlipAnimator() {
            if(reverseFlipAnimatorIn==null){
                reverseFlipAnimatorIn= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(), R.animator.flip_in);
                reverseFlipAnimatorIn.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        getImvBack().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                reverseFlipAnimatorIn.setTarget(getLinRoot());
                reverseFlipAnimatorOut= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(),R.animator.flip_out);
                reverseFlipAnimatorOut.setTarget(imvBack);
                setReverse=new AnimatorSet();
                setReverse.playTogether(reverseFlipAnimatorIn,reverseFlipAnimatorOut);
            }
        }

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private void initialiseFlipAnimator(){
            if(flipAnimatorIn==null){
                flipAnimatorIn= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(),R.animator.flip_in);
                flipAnimatorIn.setTarget(getImvBack());
                flipAnimatorOut= AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getContext(),R.animator.flip_out);
                flipAnimatorOut.setTarget(getLinRoot());
                flipAnimatorIn.addListener(new SimpleAnimatorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                        getImvBack().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        getLinRoot().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                setFlip=new AnimatorSet();
                setFlip.playTogether(flipAnimatorIn, flipAnimatorOut);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public abstract class SimpleAnimatorListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener {
        /**
         * <p>Notifies the start of the animation.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The started animation.
         */
        public abstract void onAnimationStart(Animator animation);

        /**
         * <p>Notifies the end of the animation. This callback is not invoked
         * for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The animation which reached its end.
         */
        public abstract void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) ;

        /**
         * <p>Notifies the cancellation of the animation. This callback is not invoked
         * for animations with repeat count set to INFINITE.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The animation which was canceled.
         */
        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            onAnimationEnd(animation);
        }

        /**
         * <p>Notifies the repetition of the animation.</p>
         *
         * @param animation The animation which was repeated.
         */
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            onAnimationStart(animation);
        }
    }
}
```